# Keras fit_generator StopIteration: tile cannot extend outside image

Tags: python-3.x, keras, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to fit a model using a training and testing data generator, flowed from two directories.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, horizontal_flip = True)
# output: Found 440 images belonging to 2 classes.
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
# output: Found 554 images belonging to 2 classes.

training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dir', batch_size=20, class_mode='categorical')
testing_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dir', batch_size=30, class_mode='categorical')
```

When I try to run :

```
history = model.fit_generator(training_generator, epochs=150, validation_data=testing_generator, callbacks= [early_stopping_monitor, model_checkpoint])
```

I get to the last batch and receive one of two StopIteration errors.

For a batch_size of 20, I get:

```
Epoch 1/150
21/22 [==================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.8482 - acc: 0.5619
Traceback (mostrecent call last):
...
File "...\keras\engine\\training_generator.py", line 309, in evaluate_generator
    generator_output=next(output_generator)

File "..\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 583, in get
    six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)

StopIteration: tile cannot extend outside image
```

For a batch_size of 24, I get:

```
Epoch 1/150
18/19 [==================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.8482 - acc: 0.5619
Traceback (mostrecent call last):
...
File "...\keras\engine\\training_generator.py", line 309, in evaluate_generator
    generator_output=next(output_generator)

File "..\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 583, in get
    six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)

StopIteration: -2
```

I don't understand.  I saw this : [StopIteration: generator_output = next(output_generator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709839/stopiteration-generator-output-nextoutput-generator), but that seemed to be a person making their own datagenerator, so the coder is responsible for making the generator continuously able to provide data.  But I'm using flow_from_directory, so shouldn't that be smart enough to figure out how to always provide data?

I also read that perhaps the issue might be with PIL trying to access out of bounds parts of my images.  I wrote a script to go through my image directories and open and verify them with PIL according to: [How to check if a file is a valid image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889333/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image-file), but all the directories don't raise an exception.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Since there are ~1000 images, you can open the folder containing the images and manually scan through the images in thumbnail view to see if there are any ill-formed images.

Comment: Is that what you suppose is happening?  Is there someway I can put a callback into the fit_generator function to output the file it's choking on?